# Creating deeply nested object in Prisma securely

Tags: next.js, nested, formik, prisma

I am using Prisma and Nextjs with the following data structure, with authentication using Next-Auth.

```
user
|-->profile
     |-->log
           |-->sublog
```

Right now the CRUD is sent to the database via API routes on Nextjs. And I want to write to `sublog` securely via the API.

So when I write this, it is open-ended:

```
const sublog = await prisma.sublog.create({
 data: {
         name: req.body.name,
         content: req.body.content,
         log: {
            connect: {
               id: req.body.logId,
              }
          }
       }
})
```

I have access to the user session from the frontend and backend in order to get the userID. But I am not sure how to make the form submission secure that only if the user who owns the `log` can they be allowed to submit a `sublog`.

Any ideas on how to securely submit something securely while it is deeply nested?

P.S. Note that I can turn on and off any component that edit/delete data at the frontend - but that's only on the frontend, I want to secure it on the API so that even if the client somehow is able to access a form within the `log` that doesn't belong to them, it would still push an error from the API since the client don't belong there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to make a prisma query that checks who owns the `log` before allowing the `prisma.sublog.create` to be executed. Prisma is agnostic to the concept of ownership - You need to add and check that logic yourself.

```
const fullLog = await prisma.log.findUnique({
  select: { // don't know what your model looks like, just guessing
    id: true,
    profile: {
      select: {
        userId: true
      }
    }
  },
  where: {
    id: req.body.logId
  }
});

// currentUserId = however you get the current user's id
if (fullLog && fullLog.profile.userId !== currentUserId) {
  // throw an error
}
```

Comment: Ah, great, thanks! Just a query - why do you add ```fullLog &&``` in the if statement? Wouldn't ```fullLog.profile.userId``` alone suffice?

Comment: If `fullLog` does not exist or is falsey, and you attempt to evaluate `fullLog.profile.userId`, you will get a `TypeError`. You can also use optional chaining (`fullLog?.profile?.userId`) to evaluate the express if your runtime supports it

Comment: Understood, thank you. I can confirm this is a working solution.